# Mercurial Apache windows configuration

Tags: mercurial

I tried to configure Mercurial using Apache on Windows 7. It shows list of repositories fine on the front page. But when i browse a certain repository it shows html code starting with:

```
Status: 200 Script output follows
ETag: 1305209648.82
Content-Type: text/html; charset=cp1252
```

I was thinking that it is a probelm with MIME type of Apache server. i change it with ForceType in Apache server. Ok it rendered html page somehow but there is still same header shown on the page. 
I can change repositories using hg commands from cmd. and it is also reflected from Apache server when i browse it through web interface. But i cannot push, pull from repository, neither i can clone from repositories. My hgWebConfig is:

```
[collections]
c:\webdir\repository\ = c:\webdir\repository\ 

[web]
allow_push = *
allow_pull = *
push_ssl = false
allow_archive = bz2 gz zip
```

repositories i want to publish are in c:\webdir\repository. whereas hgweb.cgi are located in c:\webdir. Apache configuration is like this:

```
ScriptAlias / c:/webdir/index.cgi/

<Directory "C:/webdir/">
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .html .xhtml
    Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

best regards,
Shahid Akram

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete step-by-step tutorial...apparently this guy managed to get HG + Apache to work on Windows 7:

[Setup Mercurial Server in Windows Machine - Tutorials are outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073380/setup-mercurial-server-in-windows-machine-tutorials-are-outdated/7088471#7088471)