# Setup Mercurial Server in Windows Machine - Tutorials are outdated

Tags: mercurial

I am refering to [HgWebDirStepByStep](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep), and trying to setup it in Windows machine (Windows 7).

1. I can no longer download hgwebdir.cgi from http://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-stable/raw-file/tip/hgwebdir.cgi. The link is dead.
2. I was told to modify `hgwebdir.cgi` content to `sys.path.insert(0, "c:/dev/Mercurial/lib")`, but I didn't found any folder in my latest Mercurial installation. I can only see there is a zip file on it.

Seems the information on the tutorial is pretty outdated. Any good guides for me to setup Mercurial server in Windows machine? As there is already an Apache in the server, I would like to make use of the Apache instead of IIS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By collecting information bits and bytes from every corners, I would like to summary the steps to setup mercurial server using Apache, with authentication feature.

---

I install [mercurial-1.9.1.win-amd64-py2.6.exe](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/windows/mercurial-1.9.1.win-amd64-py2.6.exe)

---

Add the following content to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf**

```
# Some comment so that you can find these settings later
ScriptAliasMatch ^/hg(.*) "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/hg/hgwebdir.cgi$1"
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/hg">
  Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "AuthName for Mercurial"
  AuthUserFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/hg/passwd.txt"
  <Limit GET POST>
      require valid-user
  </Limit>
</Directory>
```

---

Create the following 4 files

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\hg\hgwebdir.cgi** (Download from http://makinggames.ca/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/hgwebdir.txt and rename it to hgwebdir.cgi)

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\hg\hgweb.config** with the following content.

```
[paths]
dummy1 = d:/mercurial-repo/dummy1
dummy2 = d:/mercurial-repo/dummy2
```

**c:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\hg\passwd.txt** (Refer to this guide http://sniptools.com/vault/windows-apache-and-htaccess-authentication)

**c:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\hg.htaccess** (Just leave the file empty)

---

Initialize repositories in

```
D:\mercurial-repo\dummy0
D:\mercurial-repo\dummy1
```

This can be done using TortoiseHg, by applying "Create Repository Here", through right click on folder **D:\mercurial-repo\dummy0** and **D:\mercurial-repo\dummy1**

---

Access the mercurial through `http://your-server:81/hg/`

Comment: hgwebdir.txt  -> Oops, This Page Could Not Be Found!
404

Answer (score 6):

You can try [HgLab](http://hglabhq.com/) - a source control management system for and Mercurial Server for Windows with push, pull and streaming capabilities, repository browser, Active Directory integration, ACLs and lots of other things.

Comment: Nifty.  It uses HgSharp and IIS and does not even use regular Python.  I am a bit suspicious of a Python-free mercurial.  Anybody used this?

Comment: @WarrenP HgLab/HgSharp author here. I can say that we've been using HgLab internally for almost a year now and _never_ experienced data loss or corruption of any kind.

Comment: Wow cool. Given how hard it is to set up the Apache+Regular CPython+Mercurial on windows, this is a great idea. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have used this article to setup a mercurial server on IIS http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2010/04/08/Setting-up-Mercurial-server-in-IIS7-using-a-ISAPI-module.aspx

Comment: Sorry. I prefer to have Apache.

Comment: Apache is a better choice for Python based software, even on Windows.